# Rendering resolved promise value in Ember handlebars template

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise, handlebars.js

Is there a good way to render the result of a promise in a handlebars template?

For example, I have the following model:

```
App.TopicItem = DS.Model.extend({
  topic: DS.belongsTo('topic'),
  paddedPosition: function() {
    return this.get('topic.course.lessons').
      then(function(lessons) {
        return lessons.indexOf(topicItem);
      }).
      then(function(index){
        var position  = index;

        if (position < 0) { 
          return;
        }

        position = position + 1;

        return (position < 10 ? $.rjust(position, 2, '0') : position.toString());
      });
  }.property('topic.course.lessons')
});
```

And I would like to render the value of the position in the handlebars template like this:

```
{{topicItem.paddedPosition}}
```

Is there a good way to accomplish this?

Comment: looks like you need to wait for the `paddedPosition` to return, something like `topicItem.get('paddedPosition').then(function() {Handlebars.compile();});` not sure about ember, but that's the general approach :)

Comment: Not sure about waiting for paddedPosition as much as trying to figure out if Ember.Handlebars resolves a promise automatically.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could have the property lazily set itself, something like:

```
App.TopicItem = DS.Model.extend({
  topic: DS.belongsTo('topic'),
  paddedPosition: function(key, value) {
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      // > 1 args = this is a `set`
      return value;
    } else {
      // otherwise this is a `get`
      var _this = this;
      value = null;

      this.get('topic.course.lessons').
        then(function(lessons) {
          // do stuff based on result
          var padded = ...;
          // when the promise is resolved, set this property with the value
          _this.set("paddedPosition", padded);

          // if the promise resolves immediately, set `value` so we return
          // the calculated value and not null
          value = padded;
        });

      // returns null if the promise doesn't resolve immediately, or 
      // the calculated value if it's ready
      return value;
    }
  }.property('topic.course.lessons')
});
```

When it's first accessed it'll kick-off the calculation, likewise any time the lessons change, then it'll set itself as the result of the calculation once it's done.

This works because a computed property is called both on get and set, you can differentiate between the two by the number of arguments - 1 for get, more than 1 for set (it used to be 2, now you get 3 so the best way to detect is > 1). More on that [in the docs](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties/#toc_setting-computed-properties).

Whatever's returned from a computed property (either in get or set) is cached until its dependent properties change - in this case `topic.course.lessons`.

In the above example, when the first `get` comes in we kick off the calculation and return `null`. This is now cached as the value of the property, if anything else calls this property before the promise has resolved then it'll return `null`.

Once the promise resolves, we call `set` on the same property with the calculated value. This we just return in the setter and it's now cached as the value of the property.

Until the dependent properties change (`topic.course.lessons`), or a new value is `set` then the cached value is returned from the property.

Comment: This is very interesting, and totally worked for me. I'm trying to understand though - how it works? :)

Comment: @alvincrespo I've updated the answer with some more explanation - hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks so much for your explanation. We did some testing on this today and found that there is an intermittent issue with using this approach in handlebars. For some strange reason, even though the promise resolves and sets the value, null is still picked up by the template.

Comment: If the promise resolves instantly then it'll try and set the property but then it returns null anyway. I'll edit the answer with a possible solution to that!

Comment: @alvincrespo it works because every Model instance is a new instance of Model.

Comment: +1 on this working as of 7/7/15. Running into this and working through implementing your solution was a value way to better understand promises and function scope. Thanks for the thorough explanation!!!

Answer (score 1):

That seems like an unexpected behaviour.
There's a bug filled for that problem: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11046

Comment: After adding my +1 to that issue today, it was closed with the explanation that it's not a but, but rather a feature that doesn't exist yet. They do have plans to address this in core, and contributing to an RFC was recommended/requested.