# Ember.js computed property from store

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, promise, computed-values

I'm trying to get a simple count of objects returned by REST get request from the server to use in another controller in Ember.js

For this reason I need to make an additional request to the server. Basically here's my code and it almost works.. but not quite yet. Maybe someone can figure out why.

It return a PromiseArray, that's why I'm using `.then()` to access the properties .

```
App.TestController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    totalCount: function() {
        return this.store.find('question', {test: this.get('id')}).then(function(items) {
            var count = items.get('content').get('length');
            console.log(count); // This actually logs correct values
            return count;
        })
    }.property('question')
})
```

It does what it suppose to do and I'm getting correct values printed out in the console.log(), but when I try to use `{{totalCount}}` in the view template I'm getting `[object Object]` instead of an integer.

Also, am I properly observing the `questions` property? if the value changes in its proper controller will the value update?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rendering resolved promise value in Ember handlebars template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20623027/rendering-resolved-promise-value-in-ember-handlebars-template)

Answer (score 8):

The problem you are seeing is because your are returning a promise as the value of the property and handlebars won't evaluate that promise for you. What you need to do is create a separate function that observes `question` and then call your store there to update the totalCount-property. It would be something like this.

```
App.TestController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    totalCount: 0,
    totalCountUpdate: function() {
        var that = this;
        this.store.find('question', {test: this.get('id')}).then(function(items)     {
            var count = items.get('content').get('length');
            console.log(count);
            that.set('totalCount', count);
        })
    }.observes('question')
})
```

Comment: Thank you, Karl-Johan! That actually makes sense. However, the view still doesn't gets updated event though the console.log outputs the desired values. Am I observing the right property? Do I need to implicitly call the totalCountUpdate? In my view I'm still using {{totalCount}}, but it is stuck at 0.

Comment: Makes me think I should probably observe the totalCount property somehow? Because it is the one getting changed..

Comment: The view will automatically create an observer for totalCount. The code above looks fine. When the question changes, the totalCountUpdate will be called, which in turn should call set the totalCount, which triggers a property change notification that the UI should respond to. Can you add a jsbin reproducing the issue?

Comment: You won't need to explicitly call totalCountUpdate, thats what the `.observes('question')` part is for (ie when `question` is changed this method will run). As Miguel said, a JSBin with a sample to reproduce the problem would help a lot to diagnose this.

Comment: Please see my update. I upload the app online instead of jsbin so you can see in context what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively `totalCount` might lazily set itself, like this:

```
App.TestController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    totalCount: 0,
    question: // evaluate to something,
    totalCount: function() {
        var that = this;
        that.store.find('question', {test: that.get('id')}).then(function(items)     {
            var count = items.get('content').get('length');
            that.set('totalCount', count);
        })
    }.observes('question').property()
})
```