# Computed property with `@each` won't update

Tags: ember.js

I've created a computed property that relies on all records in the store.

I've tried making the property update on adding/removing records with `.property('todos.@each.id')`, `.property('model.@each.id')`, `.property('@each.id')`, `.property('@each')` and other combinations, no luck so far. :( When i create new records, existing recrods' property would not update.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsbin.com/UDoPajA/211/edit?output

The property is `otherTodos` on the `Todo` controller. This property is used by the `<select>` dropdown list on the page (via `{{view Ember.Select}}`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're out of scope of the collection.  You'll need to get access to the `todos` controller in order to have a computed property based off of its model.  `needs` will handle this use case.  http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/

Additionally to make an easy to access alias to the todos controller's model we use `computed.alias`. http://emberjs.com/api/#method_computed_alias

```
Todos.TodoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs:['todos'],
  todos: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.todos.model'),
  ....

  foo: function(){

  }.property('todos.@each.id')
});
```

PS note of caution, in your code you are creating multiple instances of Ember Data filter, filter collections are meant to be live collections that are long living and update as records are added/removed from the store.  You might just want to grab the model from todos and filter over it instead of creating a new store filter (which then avoids the async code as well, not that that is an issue).

Here's an implementation that would avoid that (no point in using it as a setter, you are only getting from it):

```
  otherTodos: function() {
    var model = this.get('model'),
      thisId = model.get('id');

      var todos = this.get('todos').filter(function (todo) {
        return todo.get('id') !== thisId;
      });
      var selectContent = todos.map( function(todo){
        var selectContent = {
          title: todo.get('title'),
          id: todo.get('id')
        };
        return selectContent;
      });

      return selectContent;

  }.property('todos.@each.id'),
```

Here's an updated jsbin of your code:  http://jsbin.com/UDoPajA/216/edit

Comment: Hey kingpin2k, thank you for your kind reply! I tried to apply your suggestions and failed. Here's my attempt: http://jsbin.com/UDoPajA/215/edit?js,output The worst part is that Ember ain't giving any feedback on what's wrong. Can you please modify my fiddle to demonstrate your solution? I would also greatly appreciate if you show how to grab and filter model so that i don't use costy data fitlers. PS Possible typo 'todo.@each.id': shouldn't it be todos? I tried either way, neither works for me.

Comment: Tossed it up in the answer.

Comment: I needed a setter because i was using an Ember Data to retrieve the list of records. The filter returned a promise and i had to use [the getter/setter trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20623027/rendering-resolved-promise-value-in-ember-handlebars-template) to extract the value from the promise. With your corrections, i don't need that anymore. Thank you for you help, kingpin2k! Can you please tell what exactly prevented my attempt to introduce your corrections from working?

Comment: yeah, value was undefined when returned (since it was async) and then you were returning otherTodos which would have also been undefined at the time that it was returned.

Comment: If i had no choice but to use a filter/query that returns a promise, how would i pass the value from the promise into the Ember.Select view, without breaking the binding?