# Ember solve promises in property

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a select box which content is a calculated property.
For the calculation i have to find some record from the store. Find returns a promise, which has to resolved. but how?

Here is the code:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  selectedCategory:null,
  person: function() {
      var self = this;
      //return [{"id":1,"name":"Dummy"}];

      return this.store.find('author',1).then(function(author){
        return author;
      });

    }.property('person'),
  actions: {
    submit: function() {
      //alert("Submitted!");
    } 
  }
});
```

And the jsBin: http://jsbin.com/pexolude/167/edit

ps.: i know i could make a function, and inside the `then` set the person property but i want to learn to resolve and return a promis' result. (if its possible.)

Comment: i dont want to return the promise but its resolved value.

Answer (score 1):

The method you're trying doesn't work because the computed property will return the promise itself, not the thing the promise returns.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20623551/2124849) details a method that *does* work (Ember v1.6.1) using just a computed property. Though, it's probably quicker and more readable to simply define set the property from inside an observer, as you noted.