# Where to put code from another JS library in Ember: controller, model, adapter, service?

Tags: ember.js

Wrapping another javascript library to use with Ember bindings, etc, seems like an ordinary thing to do, but I haven't found much discussion of it.

I want to filter an ember record array using distance and travel time from the [Google Maps Distance Matrix](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#distance_matrix_requests)
service. I'm just not sure where in the application to encapsulate Google's javascript. Note: this is not a question about embedding a google map, it's about getting data into ember that doesn't come from a rest/json or fixtures as in all the tutorials and examples I've found.

Would people typically do this in the controller or create new models/adapters to get benefits from store caching? Or is there another way?

update: in case that's too vague, consider this: 20 records (with a google map component etc) listed by an array controller, a text field where the user types in a home address, a couple of other inputs where they set a maximum time or distance, and a search button which filters the listed records by comparing the user requirements with the result of querying the distance matrix for the home address to the 20 records' addresses, only showing the ones close enough to their home.

Answer (score 0):

> Use of the service in an application that doesn't display a Google map is prohibited.

So,the question is really about integrating a Google map to an Ember app.

Without any doubt you'll have to add the Google JS like in any other HTML project with:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYSECRETKEY"></script>
```

So, the API is in global space and you just use it whenever you need it. Mostly all that will happen in your views, so you could wrap everything in a component. (I'm assuming that all relevant data has been passed from the controller to the view, it all depends on the design of your app.)

Comment: No, the question is about querying the maps distance matrix. We will display a google map (or several) on the page, so the terms are not an issue.

Comment: I'll update the question with some more details about what's on the page for the motivating case

Answer (score 0):

The following works, but it seems like it should be in the model/store/adapter layer.

```
App.DistanceController = Ember.Controller.extend
  origin: (->
    data = @get('data')
    data.origin if data
  ).property('data')

  destinationDistances: (->
    data = @get('data')
    data.distances if data
  ).property('data')


  data: ((key, value)->
    if arguments.length > 1
      value
    else
      _this = this
      value = null
      service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService()
      service.getDistanceMatrix(
        origins: ["London, England"],
        destinations: [
          "Bristol, England",
          "Edinburgh, Scotland",
          "Leeds, England",
          "Liverpool, England",
          "Manchester, England",
          "Newcastle, England",
          "Nottingham, England",
          "York, England"
        ],
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
      , (response, status) ->
        if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK)
          distances = []
          for destination, n in response.destinationAddresses
            distances.push {
              destination: destination
              distance: response.rows[0].elements[n].distance.text
            }

          _this.set('data', {
            origin: response.originAddresses[0]
            distances: distances
          })
      )
      value
  ).property()
```

kudos @rlivsey https://stackoverflow.com/a/20623551/395180